# handling new image file value is undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript

Working on a small guestbook posting site as part of a course however I've run into a little problem I cannot figure out.

Using a buttion to open file selection, to select an image and then process this file using the data url and create a key from the date.

However, during getting the file my data variable remains undefined all the way through and never receives the information it needs to show the image. and I'm unable to figure out the cause.

Below are the relevant parts.

```
function addPhotoClick() {
  var inputElement = document.querySelector("#image input");
  inputElement.click();
}

function processFile(event) {
  debugger;
  var data = event.target.result;
  debugger;
  var key = "diary" + Date.now();
  debugger;
  addImageEntry(key, data);
}

function initalize(){
  var addPhotoButton = document.querySelector("#image button");
  addPhotoButton.addEventListener("click", addPhotoClick);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you only need one `debugger` statement, and then you can step through the code line-by-line from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing file through `image_field_id.files[0]` instead of event. According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement), every browser which supports HTML5 should support this property.

Btw not sure if you need a button here, `<input type="file">` should create one automatically.

And always add related HTML, please, it's not 100% clear how it looks like.